# Performance Considerations: Translating on API vs ReactJS in Multi-Language Applications

Tags: reactjs, performance, optimization, symfony6

I'm currently working on a ReactJS application with a Symfony 6 backend & API Platform, and I'm grappling with a key decision regarding multi-language support. Specifically, I want to understand the performance implications of translating data on the API versus in ReactJS.

**Background:**

**Frontend:** ReactJS
**Backend:** Symfony 6

**Translation in API (Based on Accept-Language):**

```
// Example API Response (based on `Accept-Language: es`)
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Hola",
  // other fields...
}
```

I use a Normalizer to translate the data on API

**Translation in ReactJS:**

```
// Example API Response (with untranslated content)
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Hello",
  // other fields...
}
```

And after that search for "Hello" on the dictionary files

```
es.json:

{
"Hello": "Hola"
}
```

**Key Question:**

Which approach (translating on the API or in ReactJS) is more performant regarding response times, scalability, and overall user experience?

**Additional Considerations:**

How do different approaches impact server resources and response times under varying loads?

Are there any specific caching strategies that worked well for you in either approach?
I'm particularly interested in understanding the performance trade-offs and practical experiences from the community. Your insights will be precious. Thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge!